# Not sure why 'npm run dev' is not working, what to do?

Tags: node.js, github, webpack, npm-install

I am trying to run npm run dev to launch the dev mode of my github clone but it generates many errors. I've tried a lot of things but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my package.json file:

```
    "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3500",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

Here is my webpack.congif.js:

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
  mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: './src/js/',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
      '~css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css'),
      '~glsl': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/glsl'),
      '~assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      devMode,
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/html/index.html',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: './src/static/**/*',
        to: '',
        flatten: true,
      },
    ]),
  ], 
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
  mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: './src/js/',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
      '~css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css'),
      '~glsl': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/glsl'),
      '~assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      devMode,
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/html/index.html',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: './src/static/**/*',
        to: '',
        flatten: true,
      },
    ]),
  ],
```

I am not sure if I need to copy the actual title of dev or run another command for run build.

Comment: What error it returns? Can you provide parts of the error stacks?

Comment: If you will share the error messages, that would be helpful in answering

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.